# How do I extract part of a class starting with "xxx-" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<body class="some-class xxx-term-i-want-to-extract some-other-class">
```

How do I extract "term-i-want-to-extract" from the body class, knowing that this always starts with "xxx-"?

Edit: The question is about getting "term-i-want-to-extract" and storing it inside a variable, for instance. Not about removing it from the body classes or returning the body classes without it. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You may want to consider a different approach, if you can, wherein you store data like this using a `data-` attribute rather than embedding it in a class name.

Comment: @pim, did you check my answer? Don't forget to accept if it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `classList` to get a list of all the classes the `body` tag has, and then use the `$.map` function to go over them and return only the relevant ones (after removed the `xxx-` string).

```js
var classes = $.map($('body')[0].classList, function(cls, i) {
  if (cls.indexOf('xxx-') === 0) {
    return cls.replace('xxx-', '');
  }
})
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="some-class xxx-term-i-want-to-extract some-other-class">
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjoqp88s/)

```
// get the jQuery element
var $body = $('body');

// get the contents of the `class` attribute
// and use String#split to divide it into an
// array of individual class strings
var classes = $body.attr('class').split(' ');

// Array#find is used to find the first class
// that starts with the selected pattern
// and then the pattern is sliced off of the
// full class string
var xxx = classes.find(function (className) {
  return className.startsWith('xxx-');
}).slice(4);

xxx === 'term-i-want-to-extract'; // true
```

`Array#find` and `String#startsWith` are part of the ES2015 specification and therefore may not be available on all platforms. You may then need to use polyfills in older browsers like IE:

- [`startsWith` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill)
- [`find` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)